# How do you extract texts between two strings using Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, header, extract

I would like to use Python to extract blocks of texts defined by headers from temp.txt file.

temp.txt is as below where header1 (year) and header2 (month) are separated by delimiter 'tab =/t':

```
header1="2016"/theader2="Jan"
Lion Animal
Apple Food
.end

header1="2016"/theader2="Feb"
Tiger Animal
Orange Food
.end
```

I have written a script as below which works well (cmd: python script.py [year] [month] with argvs), however this allows me to extract data only for specified (months, year) and has a limitation of wildcarding months (or year) to pull out all texts. (For example, if I try to wildcard month with python script.py [year] *, it would not work.) Is there a better way?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import sys

year = sys.argv[1]
month =sys.argv[2]

with open('./temp.txt') as infile, open('./output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == 'header1="%s"\theader2="%s"' % (year,month):
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == '.end':
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)

pd.read_csv('./output', encoding='utf8', sep='\;', dtype='unicode').to_excel('./output.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet2', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add wildcards to your script:

```
if ((year == '*' or ('header1="%s"' % year) in line.strip()) and
    (month == '*' or ('header2="%s"' % month) in line.strip())
    ):
    copy = True
```

You will need to escape or quote the asterisk when calling from bash so that it doesn't get expanded to a list of files, for example:

```
python script.py [year] \*
python script.py [year] '*'
```

The general shape of your program is correct though, at a minimum you need to:

- iterate through the lines
- keep track of whether you're in a matching block or not
- write to the outfile when required

Your script pretty much does just that, so I wouldn't worry too much about optimising it.